# Could not create file error in NetBeans/Ant

Tags: java, netbeans, build, java-8

I am using NetBeans 8.0 and JDK 1.8 with MySQL driver 5.1.31.

While clean and build output window shows error ->

```
ant -f "E:\\under construction\\cps" -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
  Updating property file: E:\under construction\cps\build\built-clean.properties
  Deleting directory E:\under construction\cps\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
  Created dir: E:\under construction\cps\build
E:\under construction\cps\nbproject\build-impl.xml:893: Could not create E:\under construction\cps\build\built-jar.properties
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

and that line 893 in xml file shows ->

```
   891: <target depends="init,-deps-jar-init" name="deps-jar" unless="no.deps">
   892:       <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
   893:       <touch file="${built-jar.properties}" verbose="false"/>
   894:       <property file="${built-jar.properties}" prefix="already.built.jar."/>
   895:       <antcall target="-warn-already-built-jar"/>
   896:       <propertyfile file="${built-jar.properties}">
   897:           <entry key="${basedir}" value=""/>
   898:       </propertyfile>
   899:   </target>
```

Comment: hey jason can you please help me out in this.. ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into is that the [Ant touch](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/touch.html) command does not create missing folders by default.  You just need to modify line 893 from this:

```
<touch file="${built-jar.properties}" verbose="false"/>
```

To this:

```
<touch file="${built-jar.properties}" verbose="false" mkdirs="true"/>
```

Comment: this didn't help in my situation either.

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve your problem?  I was having the same problem and it was a file problem (nothing really to do with Netbeans or Java, except the way it accesses your file structure).  I finally disconnected from my intranet network and rebuilt so that it was all local (i.e. C drive only) and it rebuilt fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure whether it is the OS's file system issue or NetBeans itself, I tried a lot of other solutions, restarting NetBeans, the PC (thought it was some system error), turned off the antivirus, I also checked this out: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=247179... 
 Along the process I noticed that any changes on components or creating of new files was giving an error, which led me here : [Windows 10 and Netbeans: no write permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388495/windows-10-and-netbeans-no-write-permissions) 
 
 However, what actually worked for me was installation of the version of NetBeans IDE(left out Apache, GlassFish etc) I had and installed a fresh copy of that version, and voilà, all was back to normal.