# Windows 10 and Netbeans: no write permissions

Tags: windows, netbeans-8

I've installed Netbeans 8.2. on my clean Windows 10 install. Now I want to set up a new project, but when I select my source folder I get the message 'Sources folder is not writable'.

Then I decided to just change my HTML code, but when I save I've got the message 'Cannot get exclusive access to: D:\Websites... (probably opened for reading)'.

I tried to open Netbeans as administrator, but nothing seems to work. Anybody who had the same problem and could solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the cause is same as me, check your Antivirus settings, and whitelist Netbeans.

I've experienced the same an hour ago, after checking the writing permissions and creating a new project all together, nothing worked. Then I remembered I have an antivirus (Bitdefender) with Ransomware protection for my documents folder, I went to the log (of Bitdefender) and yeah, it was blocked as suspicious software, just added it to the trusted list and it works fine now.

Comment: That was exactly the same fix I found after searching for days. Bitdefender Ransomware caused the problems too :)

Comment: Yep Bitdefender Ransomware - had to just tick Netbeans IDE to Allowed under Application Access and saving successful.

Comment: I had restricted folders on Win10 and when upgrading Netbeans I needed to add the new  exe to the whitelist. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/allow-an-app-to-access-controlled-folders-b5b6627a-b008-2ca2-7931-7e51e912b034

Answer (score 1):

You might try running Netbeans as an administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by allowing the "Netbeans.exe" file through Control folder access.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If someone finds it is not solved by the solution of @Osama Islam. Try to open the file like this:

*Select the file in Projects window in netbeans* **-->** *right click on it* **-->** *Then select* "Edit". **--->** *Now try to save the content.*

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the similar issue and not running any anti virus, the issue is mainly due to permission so I fixed it by giving full access to user for that particular folder, which fixed the problem

> ICACLS "FolderPath" /INHERITANCE:e /GRANT:r username:(F) /T /C

Replace the FolderPath and username as per need

[Reference: changing permission through command prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/1100532/command-line-to-permanently-get-access-to-folder)

Answer (score 0):

Just look for programs who have the file open. In my case I executed `git diff myfile.js` which was blocking the save process.

Answer (score 0):

I faced such a problem today.
On windows 10, If you not installed any antivirus software, check your windows difender protection history. windows difender blocks the folder modification access. In protection history, find the relavent notification and select allow on device. now this error might be solved!